# Does Ubuntu 13.10 still encounter issues with UEFI and Windows 8?

Tags: 13.10, windows-8, secure-boot

It is time for a Laptop upgrade, I am going to buy a sub £300 laptop that comes with Windows 8 pre-installed. I then plan to either wipe it clean and install the new Ubuntu 13.10 or dual boot it with Windows 8.

Does UEFI/Secure Boot/Fast Boot(FastStartup) still present an issue to Ubuntu 13.10 users?

I have heard lots of problems when Windows 8 cam out about SecureBoot causing issues, just wondered whether this issue has now been ironed out or resolved yet.

Answer (score 2):

UEFI and Windows 8 is not a problem in itself. I'm running Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 on my Asus Zenbook. I don't have Secure Boot enabled though.

I think this question and the answer can help you further: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)